# How can I get the text node of an element in robot framework with selenium2library?

Tags: html, selenium, robotframework

```
<span id="spanHome" class="where-are-we" style="background-color: transparent;"> Home </span>
```

I want to get "Home" and returned. Which keyword should I use?

I tried:

```
${value}= Get Value //span[@id='spanHome']
```

But I always get None.

Comment: Sorry, just found the answer. Use Get Text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the text within a dom element, you need to use `getText()`.  You are specifying `getValue()` which is synonymous with `getAttribute("value")`.

Since your `<span>` element reveals text by it's `innerHTML`, instead of a `value` attribute, use `getText()`