# How to get all elements' text attribute at once in Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

I have some web elements which has the same prefix for their `ID` attribute. I can get these elements all at once with `get webelements`; I want to extract their text attribute with one command. I have wrote this line:

```
${elList} =     get webelements     xpath=//*[starts-with(@id, '${formName}:${row}')]
${rowList} =    evaluate            [item.get_attribute('text') for item in ${elList}]   selenium
```

Which returns:

```
Evaluating expression '[item.get_attribute('text') for item in [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f7b6c5f09d0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f7b6c5f0990>]]' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

I can't understand the problem here; BTW I'll appreciate any other solution for my issue.

**EDIT1:** I also have tried below code:

```
${elList} =     get webelements     xpath=//*[starts-with(@id, '${formName}:${row}')]
:FOR    ${item}     IN      @{elList}
\   log to console  ${item.get_attribute('text')}
```

But the console just shows `None`; it is the same for `${item.get_attribute('value')}`.

Comment: You are close. Try: ${rowList} =    Evaluate    [item.text for item in $elList]. For an explanation see http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions and http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this; I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831271/how-can-i-get-the-text-node-of-an-element-in-robot-framework-with-selenium2libra?answertab=oldest#tab-top) answer and used `${item.get_attribute('innerHTML')}` as a try. It worked pretty fine.

Comment: innerHTML would include markup, which most people would not want if they are trying to get the text.

Answer (score 2):

you could use this also.

```
@{elem} =   Get WebElements     css=._1vC4OE._2rQ-NK

:FOR  ${item}  IN  @{elem}
\   log to console  Item: ${item.text}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `text` an actual attribute or just the containing text? If it is an attribute then perhaps you can try the following method.

```
${count}=  Get Matching Xpath Count  //*[starts-with(@id, '${formName}:${row}')]
${rowList}=  Create List
:FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  ${count}+1
\  ${text}=  Get Element Attribute  xpath=(//*[starts-with(@id, '${formName}:${row}')])[${i}]@text
\  Append To List  ${rowList}  ${text}
```

Comment: Please check my answer.